# How to know the Everyone group in Sharepoint is having a user or not?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Right now I am working on to the Sharepoint 2013 on premise environment.

Scenario : I will require to authenticate users with the custom permissions which are added in a group.
It works if I add the user directly in a group. But it does not find the user if only everyone group is available.

**Question is : How to read Everyone group users in SP Group ?**

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by adding "NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users" to Everyone group.

if you dont want to send email to allusers, be sure you uncheck the send mail checkbox